# How do I change select2 box height (bootstrap)

Tags: css, jquery-select2

[image]

How do I change the height of the field?

(I do not have the code, it is infeasible. I took the example of this site: [toster.ru/q/193633](http://toster.ru/q/193633) )

Comment: Can you post your code or demo?

Comment: I do not have the code, it is infeasible. I took the example of this site: https://toster.ru/q/193633

Comment: Are you using Chosen Select (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen)?

Comment: not.. was hard to find this example..  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="inputSize">
```

CSS:

```
.inputSize    {
    font-size:18px;
    height: 75px;
}
```